# Converting field equation from position to momentum space

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, tensor-calculus, fourier-transform, spinors

**Question**

I would like to convert the following equation on position space to an algebraic equation on momentum space.  $$\partial^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\Phi_{\alpha\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{A-1}\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha_1}\cdots\dot{\alpha}_{B-1}}(x)=0$$
Here $\Phi_{\cdots}(x)$ is an (A/2,B/2) type spin tensor field where A+B=2s and s is the spin (symmetric in its dotted and undotted indices seperately). This condition selects the spin-s representation. Also;
$$\partial^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}=(\sigma^a)^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\partial_a$$
The result should be 
$$p^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\Phi_{\alpha\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{A-1}\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha_1}\cdots\dot{\alpha}_{B-1}}(p)=0$$
Where $p^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}=p_a(\sigma^a)^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}$, $~p^a=(p^0,\vec{p})$ and we are on the mass shell so $p^0=\sqrt{m^2+\vec{p}^2}$, also my metric convention is $\eta_{mn}=\text{Diag}(-1,1,1,1)$.

**Attempt**

$$\begin{align}\text
{LHS} &=\partial^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\Phi_{\alpha\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{A-1}\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha_1}\cdots\dot{\alpha}_{B-1}}(x)\\ &= (\sigma^a)^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\partial_a\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{p^0}e^{ipx}\Phi_{\alpha\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{A-1}\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha_1}\cdots\dot{\alpha}_{B-1}}(p)\\&=ip_a(\sigma^a)^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{p^0}e^{ipx}\Phi_{\alpha\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{A-1}\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha_1}\cdots\dot{\alpha}_{B-1}}(p)\\&=ip^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{p^0}e^{ipx}\Phi_{\alpha\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{A-1}\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha_1}\cdots\dot{\alpha}_{B-1}}(p)\end{align}$$
$$\implies p^{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{p^0}e^{ipx}\Phi_{\alpha\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{A-1}\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha_1}\cdots\dot{\alpha}_{B-1}}(p)=0 $$
I am not sure how or why I should conclude that 
$$\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{p^0}e^{ipx}\Phi_{\alpha\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{A-1}\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha_1}\cdots\dot{\alpha}_{B-1}}(p)\propto \Phi_{\alpha\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_{A-1}\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha_1}\cdots\dot{\alpha}_{B-1}}(p)$$
But it seems this must be the case for the conclusion to hold. I am missing something very obvious and I'm quite sure it has to do with the fact that the momentum basis is complete.

This is from the book "Ideas and methods of supersymmetry and super gravity" by I.L.Buchbinder and S.M.Kuzenko, pg 56.

Comment: Or do i conclude that the integrand vanishes and divide out the exponential factor?